# Pass data from child component to parent component Vue js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to pass data from child component "A" to parent component "B" 
(In component "B" i am using component "A")

Basically i am creating a product detail page , so on click product from category component , it will open product , page but it should also show data of only the product which is clicked , how can i achieve that ?

So i to create a route with a dynamic parameter (for the product slug or ID) and then navigate to that route when the product thumbnail is clicked.

[Codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-pine-8u9mt?file=/src/main.js)

Your suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The idomatic way for a child component to communicate with its parent in Vue is to emit events:

**child template (ProductItem.vue)**:

```
<template>
  <div>
    // component details omitted
    <button @click="$emit('show')">Show Product</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

**parent template (ProductList.vue):**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ProductItem v-for="product in products" @show="showProduct(product)" />
  </div>
</template>
```

You can also pass a payload (i.e. data) along with the event if you want.

If you're wanting to display a product detail page when the item is clicked, it sounds like what you want is to create a route with a dynamic parameter (for the product slug or ID) and then navigate to that route when the product thumbnail is clicked?

Comment: If you're wanting to display a product detail page when the item is clicked, it sounds like what you want is to create a route with a dynamic parameter (for the product slug or ID) and then navigate to that route when the product thumbnail is clicked?

Yes exactly

Comment: Yes i want the same functionality which you've talked about. i m not sure how to implement it , can you please advice ?

Comment: Have a look at the Vue router section on [dynamic route matching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html). This shows how to configure the route, and to retrieve the route params inside your page component. You can use this to load the relevant product details to display.

Comment: Can that functionality will be implemented using dynamic route matching ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was talking about. You can set up a route something like '/laptops/:slug' which will then match the URLs '/laptops/macbook' or '/laptops/thinkpad' etc. and load a component that can fetch and display the relevant product details.

Comment: I am using this - https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-routing-in-vue-js-to-create-a-better-user-experience-98d225bbcdd9/  But it redirect me on homepage while using this thing method -      this.$router.push({name:'productpage',params:{Pid:1}})

Comment: goTodetail(productid) {
      this.$router.push({path: '/productpage/'+productid+'/',name:'productpage',params:{Pid:1}})
    }


const routes = [
  { path: '/productpage', component: Productpage }
];

Comment: Thankyou for the interest in question.